# change icon color to dark black in toolbar

Tags: android, colors, toolbar, android-toolbar

i want to change the icon color to black hex code #000000 in toolbar how can i do that

Note showAsAction is set to allways
this is my code

Toolbar:-

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/tab_top"
            app:menu="@menu/top_navigation"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Menu:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_following"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_following_24"
        android:title=""
        android:enabled="true"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:iconTint="@android:color/black">

    </item>

</menu>
```

Style:-

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[here is the result im getting as we can see the icon is not black but it is dark grey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuraI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    ...
    android:tint="@android:color/black"
/>
```